# How to install new features or shortcuts?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

At home, I am using ColdFusion Builder 1.0

When I have a file open and press <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, it outputs this

```
<cfoutput></cfoutput>  or writeOutput();
```

When I have a file open and press <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, it outputs this:

```
<cfabort> or abort:
```

When I have a file open and press <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, it outputs this:

```
<cfdump var=""> or writeDump():
```

At work, I am using ColdFusion Builder 2.0.1. None of "features" described above work. I want to get them to work. What are the features called? Shortcuts? Do I need to download and install them separately? I have searched everywhere to find out how to make this happen and have had no luck. Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is referred to as "keys" under the preferences in ColdFusion Builder.  Click on the "Window" menu, then click on "Preferences".  This opens a new Preferences window.  In the left side navigation expand "General" and click on "Keys".  On the right side you will see a list of all the predefined keyboard *short-cuts* (that is my terminology for it).

There is also another "Keys" option in the preferences under "ColdFusion", and then "Profiles". This is a shorter list than the other.

Also on the right side of that preferences window is a filter box.  If you type in that box it will search the string for you.  So, for example, you can type "cfabort" in that box and it will show you the entry for that: <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.

For what it's worth, your shortcuts did not work for me either in ColdFusion Builder 2. I did some searching and found the following ColdFusion Builder 2 documentation page mentioning that some keyboard shortcuts were changed from ColdFusion Builder 1. [Keyboard shortcut enhancements](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/2.0/Using/WS287f927bd30d4b1f-29bd76b712e2288d18d-7ff8.html). The shortcuts that you are asking about have been changed. Now they are:

<kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> for `<cfoutput>`
<kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> for `<cfabort>`
<kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> for `<cfdump>`

And if you just type <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> and then wait a few seconds a menu will be displayed with the available options to pick from.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct. They are called "keys" and are located exactly where you said they would be. Could you tell me how I might have a bunch of keys installed on CFB 1 and not on CFB 2? I KNOW I didn't manually enter these. Is there a standard package that I can acquire somewhere and install/import? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @EvikJames - are you saying that your builder does not have these shortcuts installed? I have a vanilla install and all of those shortcuts came pre-defined. Unfortunately I don't really know of a place to get what you are looking for. However, looking at the dialog window above I see an `Import` and an `Export` button. I suppose you could try exporting your shortcuts from your Builder 1 install and then importing to your Builder 2 install.

Comment: In ColdFusion builder 2, a lot of these shortcuts can be used with ctrl + T {key} .  I hated it at first, but quickly got used to it.

Comment: @EvikJames - I just found [this documentation page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusionBuilder/2.0/Using/WS287f927bd30d4b1f-29bd76b712e2288d18d-7ff8.html) that mentions the keyboard shortcuts that were changed from ColdFusion Builder 1 to ColdFusion Builder 2. The ones that you mentioned in your question are listed.